# Easy resources for funnel plot

Tags: meta-analysis, funnel-plot

I'm just facing an issue of finding an easy tutorial or guide to the `funnel plot`.

Are there simple resources you recommend for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean interpreting [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funnel_plot)?  Here are a couple of other descriptions:

1.[Interpreting Funnel Plots](http://www.cochrane-net.org/openlearning/html/mod15-3.htm)

2.["Funnel plots in Meta Analysis" by Sterne & Harbord](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0061)

3.["Funnel plots for detecting bias in meta-analysis: guidelines on choice of axis" by Sterne & Egger](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11576817)

But the [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funnel_plot) is probably the best place to start. (It also contains a few other refs).